# Does PostgreSQL and other databases have a feature to reset serial/identity values?

Tags: postgresql

I recently started a new personal project. The first thing I do after thinking about it is to construct an install.php script which consists of a series of database calls where it does things like CREATE TABLE to "build the basic foundation".

When I felt reasonably confident about the structure, I ran that PHP script. From that point on, I instead used a GUI software to edit/add/delete columns and constraints, as I "fine-tuned" the database while developing the application.

For a while, I would edit the install.php for each change I did through the GUI, as to have them perfectly "synced", but after a while, as there were more changes, I said: "Screw it! This is only ever going to run on my computer anyway!" and deleted the install.php.

Now, I'm reaching some kind of "finished" state for the application, and realize that, after deleting the dummy records, various serials/bigserials are now starting at high numbers (instead of 0 or 1, as they do from the beginning). Of course, this means no *practical* problem, but it is psychologically very annoying to know that you started the "production application" with "non-vanilla" internal counters.

Is there a feature in PostgreSQL which automatically sees to it that any data remaining in the tables of the given database is "pulled back down" so they get ids like 1, 2, 3 instead of 6732, 6733, 6734, etc.? That is, ***not nuking*** the database/tables, but intelligently "resetting" them in this logical manner? I also wonder if other databases have this feature.

Note: I have foreign keys and primary keys and uniques and such all set up, so this should *technically* be possible without messing up the "relations" when the ids change.

I bet there isn't any such thing. Would be really nice if such is the case, though. Like a "database serial defragmenter" of sorts. It would even be sensible to run on a product database if you have deleted huge amounts of records for some reason, so that you never reach the maximum for a "serial" (integer).

Comment: You don't need that, simple as that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, if nobody needed this, such feature would not exist

Comment: That feature does not exist, neither in Postgres nor in any other database

Comment: sorry @a_horse_with_no_name, I didn't read the question carefully enough. You are right. There is no feature that changes existing data in the table as InsultExchange wants.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use [`ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html)  or [`setval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) function to change that "internal counter" without truncating the table.

See also http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/serial for examples.

In SQL Server you can use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to see and reset identity value of the table.

Comment: Are you really sure that you understood my question? Doesn't ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART just set the counter back? It doesn't change all the existing entries' ids?

Comment: You are right @InsultExchange, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I didn't expect that you need this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the tables and with the `RESTART IDENTITY` clause:

```
TRUNCATE [ TABLE ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ] [, ... ]
[ RESTART IDENTITY | CONTINUE IDENTITY ] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

See [truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-truncate.html) documentation.

You can also use `SELECT SETVAL` with `pg_get_serial_sequence` if you know the sequence name.

See [Sequence Manipulation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-sequence.html) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html)

Warning: Truncate deletes all the rows from a table.

Comment: TRUNCATE deletes all records.

Comment: you can create a temporary table using the original table as a source, truncate the original and then "insert select..." to copy back

Comment: There are many tables... not just one. And that sounds like way more work than doing it all over by hand... Let's just face it: it doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct that it doesn't exist as a single built-in function, but one could write a script which calls the handful of functions to make it work.  If your db is small, brute force can be a time saver for sure, but if you had 10000 tables, a short script would likely be preferable.

Comment: This is really bad and dangerous suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have the functionality to alter the value of a sequence.

Drop and recreate is the only possibility.